# Hover link border animation

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to animate the link when I hover on it. I want the top border to move down and the bottom border to move up. The borders should fade away, when the animation ends. When I hover on the link, the borders should appear and show the animation.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="/passion">My Passion</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li a {
    border-bottom: 3px transparent solid;
    border-top: 3px transparent solid;
}
ul li a::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

ul li a::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
ul li a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
ul li a:hover::before {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
ul li a:hover::after {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: can you make a snippet since I don't see html code here.

Comment: added my html fyi

Comment: when you say the border, you need the outer border to animate?

Comment: i want the animation top bottom move down, bottom border move up. The user should be able to see the transition.

Comment: Wait ya i share you in a whil. I got take a video which i did. But i want it for border.

Comment: i have share you. So the bottom border should move up on hover and top border should move down on hover. Once i  leave The exit should be in revers as shown in gif above. I want use the property background-border as there is other ways like using height and width. but i need to use background-border to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-created the example in your GIF.

For the text hover effect, make sure to use `transition` to ease the effect, e.g.:

```
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 800ms ease color;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  color: gold;
}
```

I'm displaying the `a` tag as `block` to make sure it covers the whole `li` elements when hovered.

When using CSS pseudo elements always set a content property (content: '' is you want to style it):

```
li::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: gold;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Instead of using a border, I'm animating the pseudo before en after elements on hover. You can do this by using [CSS keyframes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/).

```
li:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
   animation: flyDown 300ms ease forwards; 
}

li:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: flyUp 300ms ease forwards;
}

@keyframes flyDown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(90px)
  }
}

@keyframes flyUp {
  from {
    transform: translateY(00px)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-90px)
  }
}
```

Please find jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sanderdebr/fn4pgwv6/30/

Comment: thanks. for it. Based on your code share i modify some part to suit mine. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

**---html---**

```
<a href="#about"><span class="a-border" onclick="menuclick(this)">ABOUT US</span></a>
<a href="#creater"><span class="a-border" onclick="menuclick(this)">CREATERS</span></a>
<a href="#news"><span class="a-border" onclick="menuclick(this)">NEWS</span></a>
<a href="#contact"><span class="a-border" onclick="menuclick(this)">CONTACT</span></a>
```

**---css---**

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.a-border {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.25rem;
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.a-border::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: -3%;
    width: 106%
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}
a:hover .a-border::after {
    transform:scale(1, 1);
}
a.focused .a-border::after {
    transform: none;
}
```

**---js---**

```
function menuclick(underline) {
    var focused = document.getElementsByClassName("focused");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < focused.length; i++) {
        var under = focused[i];
        if (under.classList.contains('focused')) {
            under.classList.remove('focused');
        }
    }
    if (!underline.parentElement.classList.contains('focused')) {
        underline.parentElement.classList.add('focused');
    }
}
```